# Is there a vanilla block like Air that wont be affected by "copy Air" being turned off in MC Edit?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, mcedit

Sometimes when i start a new world i will Import a building i made in a superflat world into my new world using MC Edit. this building is actually a really big compound with an item sorter and a house which i can overtime furnish with stuff i make.

the one problem with this however is that because the world is superflat the compound is devoid of trees, some natural terrain features, grass blocks (not the dirt blocks with grass onto, the grass block which you destroy for seeds).

this can be overcomed by importing my building with the "Copy Air" option turned off but then i run the risk of trees, dirt, stone and what not getting inside and possibly obstructing my doors.

I am wondering if there is a block in Vanilia Minecraft which can act similar to air which i could walk and see though but in MC Edit isn't considered as air as such when "Copy Air" is turned off it'll still replace any blocks it's copied over

Answer (score 1):

The `structure_void` block best matches the description for what you want. It is invisible and walk-through, though it does show a small black outline when hovered over:

[image: Structure void outline]

You can give yourself this block with:

```
/give @p structure_void
```

---

As an alternative, `tripwire` is an almost invisible block:

[image: Tripwire hook]

It can be placed with string.

Comment: Then after the copy, you can use MCedit to replace all structure_void with air to fix those blocks.

Comment: Interestingly, this is using Structure Void in the reverse of its intended purpose - representing a "keep existing block" in Structure Block structures.